# How to remove default shortcuts from Swing components (like jTabbedPane)?

Tags: java, swing, hotkeys, jtabbedpane, jcomponent

I want to define and remove some shortcuts (like <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page up</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd>) from jPane and jPanel.

```
for (KeyListener keylistener: jTabbedPane1.getKeyListeners()) {

    jTabbedPane1.remove(keyListener);
}
```

This doesn't work.

Comment: Try to replace KeyBindings for the keys with empty actions (or your own actions)

Comment: Inspect ActionMap (jTabbedPane1.getActionMap()) and remove all entries which are not required for you.

Comment: Thank you, guys. Finally found : JTabbedPane jTabbedPane = new JTabbedPane();
KeyStroke ctrlTab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl PAGE_DOWN");
KeyStroke ctrlShiftTab = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("ctrl PAGE_UP");
InputMap inputMap = jTabbedPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_ANCESTOR_OF_FOCUSED_COMPONENT);
inputMap.put(ctrlTab, "none");
inputMap.put(ctrlShiftTab, "none");